# Server return error Unable to connect SMTP server when use ssl

Tags: php, ssl, cakephp-2.0, sendmail

Hi guis I have been migrating an application to new server, is an Ubuntu server but on the new server I have some problem to send emails using Cakephp 2.0.

If the host on cake mail config is `localhost` I have the following error:

`SMTP Error: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first`

Search on the internet the solutions may be is config SMTP `ssl://mydomain.com.br` on php.ini or using ssl host like this `ssl://mydomain.com.br` on cake mail config. On the first option nothing change, error persist and with host ssl on cake mail config I have the following error:

`Unable to connect to SMTP server.`

I make a simples test using only php `mail()` function and the email is been sent.

On this server I config postfix and dovecot may be this can be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

you can use 'PHPMailer'.
it's simple and easy.

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer